# if condition in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

In the following command definition:

```
\newcommand{\DrawTriangle}[5]{% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \coordinate (A) at (-1.5,-1);
  \coordinate (C) at (1.5,-1);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.5,1);
  \draw [sqangle](C) rectangle ++(-0.5,0.5);
  \draw (C) -- node[right] {#1} (B) -- node[above] {#3} (A) -- node[below] {#2} (C);
  \pic [ciangle, "#4"] {angle=C--A--B};
  \pic [ciangle, "#5"] {angle=A--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

is it possible do not execute the first `\pic` statement if `#4` is empty ?

Comment: `\ifx\relax#4\relax\else\pic [ciangle, "#4"] {angle=C--A--B};\fi` ?

Comment: @Sigur: Done so...............

Comment: You can also load `\usepackage{xifthen}` and then `\ifthenelse {\isempty{#4}}{}{\pic [ciangle, "#4"] {angle=C--A--B};}` will do the trick.

Comment: Or load `etoolbox` and use `\ifstrempty{#4}{}{\pic [ciangle, "#4"] {angle=C--A--B};}`. Or `\ifblank{#4}{}{...}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to test for empty, the simplest is possibly

```
\ifx\relax#4\relax\else\pic [ciangle, "#4"] {angle=C--A--B};\fi
```

`\ifx\relax#4\relax` is true if `#4` is empty as then it tests the two `\relax` (there are more complicated versions that work even if `#4` is `\relax` but they are probably not needed here)

Comment: `\if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax` isn't that much more complicated but works better. Why not directly use a stable version? That way new users have an easier life finding "good" code on more spots!

Comment: @Skillmon I didn't want to document `\detokenize` :-) to be honest if it gets to needing that I'd probably suggest using some prepackaged `\ifblank` test from one or other package